# the constant coefficients are penalized in the ridge logit conditional model?

Tags: regression-coefficients, logit, ridge-regression, multinomial-logit

I am estimating a conditional ridge logit model, there is very little bibliography about it, and I do not know if the constant coefficients are penalized. My model has 2 variables and 3 alternatives, so I want to estimate 8 coefficients of which there are 2 constant coefficients, 6 coefficients of the 2 variables of the 3 modes.

If you could help me with bibliography better yet.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the ESL book [The Elements of Statistical Learning II](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf), page 61, formula (3.41). The constant is not penalized.

Comment: Please post a snapshot or LaTeX transcription of the formula so the answer remains useful if the link breaks/in the absence of the book ...

Comment: but in that book it refers to linear regression, does this also apply to the conditional ridge logit model?